# How can I render data after 10 seconds of actual database update reactively in a particular template in Meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I'm currently working on a simple game called Bingo. Now I've made a spectate option in which I need to broadcast the game not real time but with a 10 second delay. Now how can I do that easily ?

Comment: Did you check Meteor.setTimeout() ? Will make the job I suppose. https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html

Comment: Do you want to broadcast to all players? If so you will need something like synced-cron package. You can update the database on a 10s schedule, and clients can pick up the database changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to use `observe` routine seems good but there are at least a couple of ways this can be implemented. One way is to delay the subscription itself. Here's a working example:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { TheCollection } from '/imports/collections.js';

Meteor.publish('delayed', function (delay) {
  let isStopped = false;

  const handle = TheCollection.find({}).observeChanges({
    added: (id, fields) => {
      Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isStopped) {
          this.added(TheCollection._name, id, fields);
        }
      }, delay);
    },
    changed: (id, fields) => {
      Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isStopped) {
          this.changed(TheCollection._name, id, fields);
        }
      }, delay);
    },
    removed: (id) => {
      Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isStopped) {
          this.removed(TheCollection._name, id);
        }
      }, delay);
    }
  });

  this.onStop(() => {
    isStopped = true;
    handle.stop();
  });

  this.ready();
});
```

Another way would be to create a local `ProxyCollection` that is only used for rendering purpose. The data would be copied from `TheCollection` to `ProxyCollection` with some delay using the same "observe technique" as in the subscription case.

In both scenarios you will need to handle some edge cases, for example:

1. Should the data be delayed on the initial load?
2. Should the update be delayed if document is removed?
3. Should the update be delayed for the user that initialized the change?

They can all be solved by utilizing and adjusting the technique presented above. I believe though, they're outside the scope of this question.

### EDIT

To prevent delays on the initial data load you can update the above code as follows:

```
let initializing = true;

const handle = TheCollection.find({}).observeChanges({
  added: (id, fields) => {
    if (initializing) {
      this.added(TheCollection._name, id, fields);
    } else {
      Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isStopped) {
          this.added(TheCollection._name, id, fields);
        }
      }, delay);
    }
  },
  // ...
});

// ...

this.ready();
initializing = false;
```

At first, it may not be obvious why this works, but everything here is being executed within a fiber. The `observeChanges` routine "blocks" and it first calls `added` for each document of the entire initial dataset. Only then it proceeds to the next part of your publish method body.

Something that one should be aware of is because of the behavior described above, a subscription may be stopped before the initial data set is processed and so, before the `onStop` callback is even defined. In this particular case it shouldn't hurt but sometimes it can be problematic.

Comment: But I don't want to delay the data on the initial load.
how can I do that ?

Comment: @Al-aminNowshad I've updated the answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.observe()`. It will tell you when added/changed events fire and you can do whatever you want in those events. Documentation [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe).

```
CollectionName.find().observe({
    added: function (document) {
        //do something here, like delaying the update
    },

    changed: function (document) {
        //do something here, like delaying the update
    },
});
```